# vnc server disconnects when unplugging hdmi

Tags: 22.04, hdmi, vnc

I am using vnc to share my ubuntu machine screen to windows vnc client and it works fine but when I disconnect the ubuntu machines HDMI to monitor connection the vnc server stops serving the feed and my vnc client display freezes. When I did some research I saw that I have to set `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` inside the `/boot/config.txt` file but this is for raspberry pi os what is the equivalent solution for Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS? Thanks in advance.

Link where I found the raspberry pi vnc solution: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=162734

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in ubuntu 22.04 you have to modify:  `/boot/firmware/config.txt`
Open it as admin and:

1. (*) comment line (add #):

   `dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d`
2. add following lines (That will get you a 1080p desktop):

   `hdmi_force_hotplug=1`

   `hdmi_group=1`

   `hdmi_mode=16`

(*) VNC is designed to mirror the local display - if the local display never comes up, for example, because there is no monitor attached, then there is nothing for VNC to mirror. You need to either bring up the local display somehow, or run a dedicated 'in memory' desktop to attach the VNC server to.

Founf [here](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=341820#p2047727): it worked for me (RPI4 & Ubuntu 22.04)